# Retrieving data on PostBack: Request.Form vs. TextBox.Text

Tags: asp.net

Is there a difference between retrieving data that was sent on a postback using (1) `Request.Form` of type `NameValueCollection` and (2) `<ControlID>.Text` (or `SelectedValue` or other)? Consider the following code-behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(...) {
    if (IsPostBack) {
        Validate();
        if (IsValid) {
            // APPROACH (1): Retrieve POST data from the Request.Form object:
            NameValueCollection post = Request.Form;
            string username = post["username"];
            // logic continues...
        }
    }
}
```

vs. the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(...) {
    if (IsPostBack) {
        Validate();
        if (IsValid) {
            // APPROACH (2): Retrieve Control text directly:
            string username = UsernameTextBox.Text;
            // logic continues...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between these two approaches? Any reasons to favor one over the other (in certain cases maybe)? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically same. We normally use the second approach.

The latter is strongly type, and it throws compile-time error if a control doesn't exist.

Only time I use ***NameValueCollection*** is to retrieve a control which is added ***dynamically*** at client-side ***using Javascript***, and the form is posted back to server.